# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-studio

I am new to Android (day 1) and i was taught to display images (`ImageView`) using `viewFlipper` today. `ViewFlipper` works fine for low number of images (5 or so). But I'm unable to use it for displaying 22 images as i get an out of memory error, and the app force closes. So i read here in StackExchange to replace `ViewFlipper` with `ViewPager`, and i get the following errors.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Logcat:
[Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10207972/). Sorry to patebin, i couldn't format the logcat well here.

Second `Activity` Java Class:

```
package com.droidrish.www.rishabhtatiraju;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class photoActivity extends Activity{
ViewPager vf;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photography);
    vf = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
}
```

Second `Activity` Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<ViewPager
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/viewpager">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p2"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p3"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p4"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p5"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p6"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p7"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p8"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p9"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p10"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p11"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p12"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p13"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p14"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p15"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p16"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p17"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p18"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p19"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p20"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p21"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p22"/>
    </ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest XML:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".photoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.droidrish.www.rishabhtatiraju.photoActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class ViewPager

Because using `ViewPager` in xml but in Activity code trying to cast `ViewPager` to `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` class.

Use `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in xml instead of `ViewPager` :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/viewpager">
....
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Yes, ViewPager is no longer any concern, thanks. But i now have a new set of errors: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10208639/

Comment: Please note that when i click on the image leading to the second activity, the app force closes and shows these errors in logcat.

Comment: @RishabhTatiraju: `Out of memory on a 10469392-byte allocation.` probably due to image size. search on google you will get lot of posts regarding same issue. for testing use small sizes images

Comment: Should i also post the code of main activity and its xml?

Comment: @RishabhTatiraju: my suggestion is finish this question by accepting it as answer is this answer help you in fixing issue as posted in question. for next issue instead of editing original question make a new question with related part of code and error logs. thanks

Comment: Clearly its an image size issue. I have images sized 1024x768, all of them. I'm dropping ViewPager and heading to webView to display an online collection of my photos. Thanks again. I'll update this if i get any breakthrough.